# Will the byte 90 after byte 58 affect it so that it cannot be interpreted as the command popq %rax?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code

I am doing an `ROP attack` homework recently.

Now I found a garget `addval_219`, which has a byte `58` that represents `popq %rax` .My idea is when the gadget uses a popq instruction, it will pop my data from the stack.

when use `objdump`. I have the disassembly code of `addval_219`

```
00000000004019a7 <addval_219>:
  4019a7:   8d 87 51 73 58 90       lea    -0x6fa78caf(%rdi),%eax
  4019ad:   c3                      retq
```

And when I set the address of `addval_219` `0x4019ab`. When the code is executed, I have some questions.

1. what instruction byte `90` will now be translated into?
2. Will the byte `90`  after byte `58` affect it so that it cannot be interpreted as the command `popq %rax` ?
3. If byte `90` is replaced with another byte, can I still jump directly to the address where byte `58` is located?

Comment: `90h` is a NOP opcode. `58h` is not affected by what follows.

Comment: Have you tried checking the instruction set reference for what instruction `90` is?